# OS X 10.11.6, Parallels Desktop 12, and Windows 10 - Windows hangs at login screen

Tags: windows, macos, windows-10, virtualization, parallels

I have a Windows 10 Enterprise VM in Parallels Desktop 12 on my MacBook Pro. It was working fine for awhile, but a few weeks ago I inexplicably ran into a problem - the VM boots without issue and begins to automatically log in to Windows, and it just hangs forever at the "Welcome" spinner on the login screen.

I'd rather not reinstall my VM if I can help it. Is there any way to fix this? The answers I found in the Parallels KB all dealt with actual errors. I'm not seeing any errors - just an inability to log in.